# can't load ubuntu in low-graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu, installation

Yesterday, I decided to install ubuntu on my laptop, I did it by wubi, I wanted to try ubuntu, but I had some problems. I chose ubuntu, then purple screen some seconds and black, i was wairing for 5 min and restart. Then I found information about this problem, and I entered into GRUB and choose nomodeset, me proposed to enter in low-graphics mode, then I push ok and then I saw window with four radio button, I push enter, but nothing happens, I waited 5 minutes and restart.
What advice you can give me? Maybe install ubuntu without wubi near windows?
My laptop: acer pentium(R) dual-core t4500 2.3 ghz. video-adapter: modile Intel 4 series express chipset family.
OS: windows 7
Sorry for my english, I work in this way:)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu have you tried? Try with 12.04 live CD.

Comment: Related: [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)